# MalformedByteSequenceException Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml

I am coding an *XML* parser class and when I run it sometimes it works fine but another time it doesn't work and throws this exception:

> MalformedByteSequenceException Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Can anyone provide some information as to why?

Here is my code:

```
package TRT;



import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Gundem {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Gundem gundem=new Gundem();
        try {
            URL url=new URL("http://www.trt.net.tr/rss/gundem.rss");
            URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder=builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document=docBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());

            Element element=document.getDocumentElement();

            Node node=(Node)element.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());


            NodeList nodeList=node.getChildNodes();
            Node channelNode=(Node)nodeList.item(0);
            System.out.println(channelNode.getNodeName());

            NodeList childNodeListOfChannelNode=channelNode.getChildNodes();

            for(int i=0;i<childNodeListOfChannelNode.getLength();i++){
                Node childNodesOfChannelNode=(Node)childNodeListOfChannelNode.item(i);
                System.out.println(childNodesOfChannelNode.getNodeName());

                if(childNodesOfChannelNode.getNodeName().equals(Constants.ITEM)){
                    Item item=new Item();
                    NodeList itemList=childNodesOfChannelNode.getChildNodes();
                    for(int j=0;j<itemList.getLength();j++){
                        Node childNodeOfItem=itemList.item(j);
                        if(childNodeOfItem.getNodeName().equals(Constants.TITLE)){
                            item.setTitle(childNodeOfItem.getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(item.getTitle());
                            System.out.println(gundem.dumpingInputAsHex(item.getTitle()));
                        }
                        else       if(childNodeOfItem.getNodeName().equals(Constants.DESCRIPTION)){
                            item.setDescription(childNodeOfItem.getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(item.getDescription());
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        System.exit(0);  // this line is for solving that problem; JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2


        }

    public String dumpingInputAsHex(String input){
        return String.format("%40x",new BigInteger(1,input.getBytes()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your document using UTF-8?

Comment: I'm guessing there was a bad byte in a UTF8 sequence.

Comment: (You can Google UTF8, you know.)

Comment: do you check the return code to see if you could have gotten an error?

Comment: "bad UTF8" is also referred to as "windows UTF8" or "UTF8+BOM" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely case is that you are attempting to parse, as UTF-8, a document that is encoded with some other character set such as ISO-8859-1.  The parser encountered an ISO-8859-1 character with a value that is not allowed to occur by itself in UTF-8.

To solve the problem you will need to determine the *actual* encoding of the document and then create your own `InputStreamReader` from the return value of `connection.getInputStream()`, specifying the correct encoding. Then create an `InputSource` from the reader and pass *that* to `docBuilder.parse()`.

Further Research:

I ran your code in Eclipse (JDK 7) and was able to reproduce the error.  I then set Exception breakpoints in Eclipse on both `MalformedByteSequenceException` exceptions, and it DID NOT fail.  Tracing into the code, I was able to see, one time only, the invalid characters in the input buffer.  This indicates to me there's a race condition bug somewhere in the Xerces parser.

You may have to file a bug with Oracle.

Comment: if you download the feed link in the code, it does claim to be utf-8.

Comment: also, you can just specfy the encoding on the InputSource instead of doing the stream wrapping yourself.

Comment: how can ı determine the encoding type of the xml document?

Comment: Firstly,thanks for your interest,I searched about race condition and learned that is a problem with threads but ı use one thread which is the main thread for parsing,and ı dont understand "You may have to file a bug with Oracle." how can ı do that? thanks already..

Comment: Try http://bugs.java.com/ - Your code, with references to the `Item` class removed, should be sufficient for Oracle to reproduce the problem.